# 6.765 - 6.795 MHz ISM band for prototype testing

Tags: legal, hf, canada

Not strictly a ham radio question, but I figure this is the most knowledgable community to ask. This question pertains to Canada, specifically.

If I were wanting to build a prototype for a commercial product (which, when complete and licensed, would operate on a licensed frequency), would I be able to use the HF ISM band (6.765 - 6.795 MHz), or any other ham band, without a commercial license for prototype testing?

Although I have an amateur license, I imagine I can't use the ham bands for testing as, even though it's just testing and development (non-commercial use), it's for developing a commercial product and therefore not "amateur", but the ISM bands (I believe) are not subject to such restrictions.

Comment: actually, when it comes to designing commercial products, https://electronics.stackexchange.com would be the more knowledgeable (and much wider) community. However, I interpret your question as being about amateur radio regulations, so it's really on-topic here, more than anywhere else.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yeah, I wonder if it's worth a meta thread to clarify this sort of thing? It feels fairly on-topic to me but the current [on-topic help page](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) isn't totally clear on where ISM questions fall. It implies **not** ("wireless consumer devices" may not be asked) but if so I guess that would also rule out things like [LowFER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LowFER)??

Comment: My personal position on this is that if something is questionable, it should only be removed or considered off-topic if there's somewhere obviously better for it to be. Otherwise you end up with topics that can't be asked anywhere. Of course, my position is rather biased on this one :)